# DR among AWS and GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, redis

We are working on a multi-cloud DR design among GCP and AWS. Rest of infra is well in control. However, the AWS have a ElasticCache cluster using REDIS. We desire to make a cold or warm copy of same in GCP. Any thoughts?

A REDIS DR in GCP that can work as failover.

Comment: You must have a VPN connecting both clouds. Memory store does not provide external public IP addressing. Add more details on failover requirements.

Comment: VPN is there, We are looking to evaluate both Cold and Pilot light DR for Redis running in AWS failing over to GCP. The traffic will be routed through Route53. We are new to Redis failover and hence trying to understand whats best way to implement multi-cloud failover for Redis Cache.